# How to achieve layout without using absolute/relative positioning?

Tags: css, layout, positioning

Here's my current layout achieved using absolute/relative positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/keruilin/xB8Bt/50/

To make a long story short, the use of absolute/relative positioning is causing the content not to display properly in a JavaScript pop-up.

What other way can I achieve the layout without using absolute/relative positioning?

Comment: Do you have a chance to draw a small sketch on how this should look like? I can't really recognize the layout clearly.

Comment: I too would like to see a sketch on how this is suppose to lay out.

Comment: Guys, Votey actually answered my question, but if you'd still like to see what the layout should be, I'll post a screenshot.

Comment: I would because I think there's a lot of room for improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I simply remove all the `position: absolute;` and `position: relative;` the layout does not change substantially (perhaps some margins and padding are tweaked a bit, but that's easily remedied). The elements stay in their same basic locations.

This is because you've already got in place the `float: left`; and `clear: both;` rules required to position elements where they belong.

Unless this example is oversimplified from the real markup, you shouldn't have any trouble stripping out the absolute/relative positioning.